# Find what number a string is in a List

Tags: c#, string, list

I want to be able to know what number a string is in one list so I can match it with a string in another list.

Something like:

`myList[1] would be 1
myList2[5] would be 5`

Sorry if I'm not clear, but this is really hard to explain.

Comment: Please try again, show examples of your lists's contents.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to explain more, Do you have `List<string>` which has some numbers ? Put some C# code for what you have tried and try to explain what you actually need.

Comment: Sorry guys, I couldn't think of the word "Index" I completely forgot that's what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number you're referring to is called the index.

You can find the index of a string in your list by using the `List<T>.IndexOf()` method.

```
int indexOfFoo = myList.IndexOf("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. I didn't know how to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

To find the index of a string in a list of strings:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" };
var indexOfY = myList.IndexOf("y");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myList.IndexOf("string")` to get the index of the item in your list.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'm not sure if that is what you're asking, but that is how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
yourList.IndexOf("urstring")
```